# Sails JS forbidden POST request

Tags: sails.js, postman

I'm trying to learn Sails JS and obviously REST API.

I've created a user model which I think works fine (it communicates data with my db). I've also created a signup controller with 4 needed inputs to store a new record in my user collection. (Some other data are generated by this controller to complete the record at the moment of the registration)

I would like to test this controller with POSTMAN, so I go to my `routes.js` and see :

```js
'POST  /api/v1/entrance/signup': { action: 'entrance/signup' },
```

But when I enter a POST request at `192.168.1.13:1338/api/v1/entrance/signup` with my 4 needed inputs declared I have this answer : **Forbidden**

I don't know what I do wrong. I've also enabled *rest*, *shortcuts* and *actions* in my `blueprints.js`

Does someone has an idea ?

Comment: Whats the name of the controller?

Comment: The name is signup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said below, removing CSRF protection is not an answer as it may expose the api to a security breach. I currently use JWT but it doesn't seems to be as secure as CSRF token so the only right way is to include the token in every HTTP's request header.

Comment: Disabling this option is a security breach.

Comment: It would've been better to disable it for only that particular route, rather than for whole application https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes

Comment: Please do not do this, this shouldn't be the accepted answer. Refer to https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/deployment#?enable-csrf-protection

Comment: It's quite an old post. I will correct this answer.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is indeed related to [cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), but disabling the corresponding security rule altogether is quite obviously not a solution. CSRF and its treatment in sailsjs are well described in the corresponding part of the [manual](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/csrf). In short, for POSTs to work you have to include _csrf in your requests. E.g. in a view template:

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%- _csrf %>" />
</form>
```

Comment: How can we use rest api with csrf enabled though? In sails 1.0 I dont have a `security/grant-csrf-token` endpoint.

Comment: @Noitidart That csrf token endpoint is no longer provided by default. See the upgrade docs for 1.0. https://sailsjs.com/documentation/upgrading/to-v-1-0