# Sails 1.0 POST route gives 403 error

Tags: sails.js

In my routes.js file, I have defined a route like this:

`'PUT   /api/v1/entrance/login':                        { action: 'entrance/login' },
  'POST  /api/v1/entrance/signup':                       { action: 'entrance/signup' },
  'POST  /api/v1/entrance/send-password-recovery-email': { action: 'entrance/send-password-recovery-email' },
  'POST  /api/v1/entrance/update-password-and-login':    { action: 'entrance/update-password-and-login' },
  'POST  /api/v1/deliver-contact-form-message':          { action: 'deliver-contact-form-message' },
  'POST /api/v1/getEventsForICalUrl':                    'IcalController.getEvents',`

I have just used the default generated code and added the last route for `getEventsForIcalUrl`.
I created an `IcalController` inside the controllers directory and it has an action `getEvents` which simply renders a json like this:

```
module.exports = {


  /**
   * `IcalController.getEvents()`
   */
  getEvents: async function (req, res) {
    console.log("hit here");
    let events = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      events.push({foo: "bar" + i});
    }
    return res.json({
      events: events
    });
  }

};
```

My problem is that whenever i try to access this controller from the client side, it gives 403 forbidden error. 
When I change the route from POST to GET, it works as expected(ofc I am using proper GET/POST request from client end for the route).

Not sure what is breaking. 
I also checked the logs. Its printing "hit here" when I use the GET. 
In my policy file looks like this(as it was generated. I did not change it):

```
module.exports.policies = {

  '*': 'is-logged-in',

  // Bypass the `is-logged-in` policy for:
  'entrance/*': true,
  'account/logout': true,
  'view-homepage-or-redirect': true,
  'deliver-contact-form-message': true,

};
```

And my "is-logged-in" policy file is this:

```
module.exports = async function (req, res, proceed) {

  // If `req.me` is set, then we know that this request originated
  // from a logged-in user.  So we can safely proceed to the next policy--
  // or, if this is the last policy, the relevant action.
  // > For more about where `req.me` comes from, check out this app's
  // > custom hook (`api/hooks/custom/index.js`).
  console.log("req.me=" + req.me);
  if (req.me) {
    return proceed();
  }

  //--•
  // Otherwise, this request did not come from a logged-in user.
  return res.unauthorized();

};
```

I just put that console.log in this file. others are as they were by default generation from `sails new`.

The logs show that using POST, this one does not get hit either.(I dont see the "req.me=".. in console.logs.) But this one gets hit when Using GET.

It seems that the route is not working for POST requests. I wonder if its an  error in sails js itself or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you tried the `GET` request from the browser and the `POST` from postman ?

Comment: i tried POST from my sails js front end(Which uses axios library). Also checked network traffic in chrome @HamzaFatmi

Comment: I think maybe you are not sending the cookies with the request when you are doing the `POST`, since when doing the `GET` from the browser, it's done automatically for you.

Comment: How do you make post request by submitting a form ?

Comment: did you ever this to work? @rahulserver

Comment: @Logan_B I did open an issue on github. The app was for internal use only, so I just used get requests. Certainly Its not yet production ready. 
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4382#issuecomment-386913851 is the comment i received. But makes not much sense as I dont know what "Cloud SDK" is.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201793

Comment: @har-wradim i don't want to turn off the csrf tho

Comment: Turning off csrf is in no way a solution. That's a workaround. Code can not be put to production this way.

Comment: @Logan_B You shouldn't: I stress that very idea twice on that page.

Answer (score 6):

There are at least two ways how to solve this.
Probably you are using csrf. If you do, your config probably includes this:

```
module.exports.security = { // With Sails <1.01 this probably is in another file
    csrf: true
};
```

And (if you are using sails v1.01), you should make this route:

```
'GET /csrfToken': { action: 'security/grant-csrf-token' },
```

So, to get data on your frontend, you just:

```
function get_some_records(object_with_data) {
  $.get("/csrfToken", function (data, jwres) {
    if (jwres != 'success') { return false; }
    msg = {
      some_data: object_with_data,
      _csrf: data._csrf
    };
    $.post("get_some_records", msg, function(data, status){});
  });
}
```

But if you are using some background jobs, Sails wont give you csrf easily(there is some way probably). So , you just create a route like this:

```
 'post /get_some_records': {
     action: 'home/get_some_records',
     csrf: false
  }
```

Comment: i added this and i'm still getting forbidden, however, this does work in postman

Comment: Did you have to do something on your client side for this to work? postman works but when from my angular 6 client side, i still get 403 error, even with the csrftoken in the body

Answer (score 5):

You probably use a Rest client to test (like Postman). Simply disable the csrf protection. in the /config/security.js file

```
csrf: false
```